# How to modify the gradle version when Android studio creates the project

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio version is as follows：

**Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1**

**Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922, built on July 27, 2021**

When I create a new android project, the default version of gradle is 7.0.0, and then java11 is required to run, how to modify the gradle version used by Android studio when creating the project.

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace with `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"`
then you can use with java 8

Comment: it didn't work，Changed, 
Both of them have been changed to 29
compileSdk 29 
targetSdk 29

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip` in your `gradle-wrapper.properties`

and

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'` in your `build.gradle`